# Excel cannot open links using Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a URL that doesn't support **IE**. Because we're not going to do compatibility with Internet Explorer.

But, excel uses IE by default to open links.

We seem to have a problem with the method that does not support IE.
Such as `youtube`. Insert the link `https://www.youtube.com/xxx` in excel.

Win10 automatically opens `edge` through group policy

I want to know what `youtube` did to tell IE that he didn't support it.

Or what better way do I have to set up Excel to open links through `edge` or `chrome`?

**By the way, wps works fine**

Comment: Excel doesn't use IE by default, it's what you tell it to use by default. Maybe this will help you: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4836-excel-change-browser-hyperlink.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found that the default browser I set is used in the latest Excel instead of IE, but our company uses Excel2016 by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest versions of office, opening the inserted link uses the default browser set by the user, which is a problem with current `office 2016` and previous versions

Comment: excel version 2111 (14701.20226)